# load is not working in jquery, help please

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to fix one jquery issue my code is

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         //if the document is ready
        $('#img').load(function() { 
            //if the image is loaded
            pic_real_height = this.height;
            //finding the height of the image
            $('#img').css('margin-top', 150 - pic_real_height / 2 + 'px');  //setting the margin-top to align the image verticall middle in the container<br>
        });  
    });
</script>
```

This scripts works in all browsers except IE and opera, How can I fix this issue ?
Actually I want to set the image vertically middle in a container (div)

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pic_real_height = $(this).height();
```

Comment: Actually $('#img').load(function() has the problem